# ListView contents in Android are null when clicked on

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have a simple SQLite database that is a table of winners in a card game.  The table has columns for the unique ID, name, score, date and a set of data which will be used later (a string array).  I'm able to query from and render the data into a listview (which was much harder to figure out than I expected).  Now, I want to click on an item in the listview to launch another activity using the data from the string array.  However, when I go into the onItemClick method, getItem always returns null.  Here's the class:

```
    public class NewHoFListViewActivity extends Activity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    NewHoFListAdapter ListAdapter ;

    ArrayList<String> ID_ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> scoreArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> dateArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView myListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_hof_list_view);

        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String item = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the data from this row in the database.
                //String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        ShowSQLiteDBdata() ;

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {



        ID_ArrayList.clear();
        nameArrayList.clear();
        scoreArrayList.clear();
        dateArrayList.clear();

        cursor = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM winners", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ID_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WINNERS_COLUMN_ID)));

                nameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WINNERS_COLUMN_NAME)));

                scoreArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WINNERS_COLUMN_SCORE)));

                dateArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.WINNERS_COLUMN_DATE)));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        ListAdapter = new NewHoFListAdapter(NewHoFListViewActivity.this,

                ID_ArrayList,
                nameArrayList,
                scoreArrayList,
                dateArrayList

        );

        myListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

        cursor.close();
    }
```

}

I've left in the other approach I've tried (commented out); both (item and cursor) return null.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Problem is you initialized listView but didn't set adapter and called itemClickListener... call ShowSQLiteDBdata(); after initializing listview

Comment: Thanks--that was a schoolboy error on my part...thank you for catching that.  Now, when I call String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); it's returning an integer that represents the row index.  How do I access the data contained in that row?

Comment: get item like this Object obj = myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position); then get this object in string, String strObj = obj.toString(); try this if it helps i will post answer then you can accept it :)

Comment: I ended up doing this:  // Get the data from this row in the database.

                    int rowIndex = (int) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    //View rowView = myListView.getChildAt(rowIndex);

                    View rowView = myListView.getFocusedChild();

                    rowView = myListView.getChildAt(rowIndex - parent.getFirstVisiblePosition());

                    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);

                    String name = (String) nameTextView.getText();

Comment: Did you get it all work? Your approach is messy :D

Comment: It's working fine, but I'm happy to entertain suggestions for improvement.  I'm pretty new to UI programming, so lots to learn. :-)

Answer (score 0):

parent.getItemAtPosition(position) method

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I tried that and item is still null unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that you are returning your desired "String" object from "getItem()" method of your adapter **NewHoFListAdapter** class.

Comment: Thanks....it was returning null as a default....I'm a device driver guy new to UI work, so I'm still ramping up here...how do I format the data from my DB correctly to return the needed values in this method?

Comment: Write "return nameArraylist.get(position);" in "getItem()" method of your adapter (NewHoFListAdapter).